# docker failed to bind port on 0.0.0.0:443 on a macvlan network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-networking

I'm running into a problem that has be stumped, I simply don't understand why what is happening is... happening.

First of all, the situation;
I have 1 network running:
macvlan_network (configured as an external macvlan network on the 192.168.10.x segment)

My example docker-compose file for portainer looks like this:

```
services:
  portainer:
    image: portainer/portainer-ce:latest
    container_name: portainer
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /volume1/docker/portainer:/data
    ports:
      - 80:8000
      - 443:9000
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      macvlan_network:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.10.11
    mac_address: c0:eb:23:9b:7a:f9

networks:
  macvlan_network:
    external:
      name: macvlan_network
    driver: macvlan
```

When I try to run this container, I get:

> ERROR: for portainer  Cannot start service portainer: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint portainer (aaa754fb6b68be51d679420fd49b1c5bc9696af517c7d50c77dba75e1c7aeacb): Bind for 0.0.0.0:443 failed: port is already allocated

But... how can this be? 0.0.0.0 is a local loopback. Does that mean it ignores the nmacvlan network entirely? Or is it perhaps trying to do this on the bridge network (which is technically not a macvlan), running on a single device and as such interfering?

When instead of putting a port on 0.0.0.0, but change it to:

```
    ports:
      - "192.168.10.11:80:8000"
      - "192.168.10.11:443:9000"
```

I get

> ERROR: for 6ad1e75e8279_portainer  Cannot start service portainer: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint portainer (04fa9e1d91c229e55c57fb66b0efe89b05c3039d29fc1c048270d383fb9518f8): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 192.168.10.11:443: bind: cannot assign requested address

Am I correct in assuming that this is somehow interfering with the port assignment on the actual host device? Because I always assumed that a macvlan network would resolve this and allow all ports on each separate virtual device.

The macvlan_network is defined as follows:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "macvlan_network",
        "Id": "0cad5174370c95521fc52dce72128a9a353f2cc124670074bc7effc125e8d416",
        "Created": "2023-10-05T23:59:42.889703967+02:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "macvlan",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "192.168.10.0/24",
                    "IPRange": "192.168.10.1/24",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.10.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
                        "6ad1e75e82793c2c14e15120c9aa27f72d4b6e19d556a6ce6c49ff950b003c53": {
                "Name": "6ad1e75e8279_portainer",
                "EndpointID": "d24966ad3efe46caca837cd3e9467f7efdfb6dc53e428ac1d9e3de921bf4b30c",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:0a:0b",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.10.11/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "90e3601b3a96b998456d469ace8390f42830dd6b84402410290678210c934a87": {
                "Name": "mosquitto",
                "EndpointID": "5fa13668106a9bcb64cc06db899a49734a4b34289f8c1a7b33ef3b3d414a6088",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:c0:a8:0a:0a",
                "IPv4Address": "192.168.10.10/24",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }

      }
]
```

Comment: The `service`->`port` in the compose yaml defines the port that is mapped on the host network. The network you defined is used for the internal container ports 8000 and 9000.

Comment: `0.0.0.0 is a local loopback` ... no, it isn't. It's just a general agreement that `0.0.0.0` is a configuration directive for `all available interfaces`. This usually also includes the loopback interface, but that's it.

Comment: Ah, I see. So port mapping on macvlan networks is basically useless? And if I were to want to change the ports, I'd need to proxy them from inside the container itself?

Comment: Either that or you place a proxy inside the desired vlan.

Comment: Why even map ports when you are using macvlan? You can access the services in the container with `192.168.10.11`. (You do need a macvlan interface on the host side as well though, AFAIK. Otherwise it would only work for your LAN hosts but not the container host itself.) Besides, the latter ports in the port pairs (i.e., 8000 and 9000) refer to ports of the container, while the former ones (i.e., 80 and 443) refer to ports of the host. (Btw, I hope you at least understand that, you are supposed to use an IP different from the one the host use when you are using macvlan...)

Comment: Yes, I do understand that and am using it. The host has a different IP address. I was just confused since I figured defining the ports was how they are exposed on the container itself. I hadn't realized it was on the host.
The reason I wanted this was because I am running a service which binds various ports which I would like to change, however it doesn't provide a way for me to do so (no config). So I don't want it to run on port 8000, but rather on port 80, but I can't configure that in the service itself, so I have to use a proxy for that. Which is fine, since it answers my question :)